# BIRT Reports column not spanding the whole row as desired

Tags: birt

I am fairly new to BIRT reports.

In the BIRT reports designer I have added a 2nd row to my table which is binded to a data set. In this 2nd row I want 1 column from my data set to take up the whole row.

So what I did was to add the second row and merge all the columns in that row to form one column. I then added a text field with Dynamic HTML Text.

```
<VALUE-OF>row["ITEMDESCRIPTION"]</VALUE-OF>
```

The problem I have is that the data is not taking the whole row. It is being wrapped into only a small section of the row. I must be missing something. Can someone help me with this pls.

I'm attaching both the way the end report looks like and also the screenshot of the set up in the designer.

End Result
[image]

Designer (you can see all the rows merged in the second row of the table and in the properties i can see a colspan of 10 for that single column)
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the asnwer to this question is to make the field element inline style rather than block and also to check the No Wrapping check box for this field int he designer.